# Induction and proof , proofing a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]
How do you prove this by induction? I'm used to proofing simple geometric series by induction but this one is very complicated. How can I approach this, or maybe give me an answer and show me how you did this in detail? Would really appreciate your help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For $n=0$, the statement is true.

Let's suppose it's true for $n$:

$$ h_{n} + h_{n-1} + h_{n-2} = 2h_{n-1}+ 2h_{n-2} + h_{n-3}\leq 2h_{n-1}+ 2h_{n-2} + 2h_{n-3}\leq 2 \cdot 2 ^n = 2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of the same result with the Fibonacci sequence.

The Fibonacci sequence is given by $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ and $F_{n} = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ for all $n\ge 2$.  The conclusion holds for $F_0 = 1 \le 2^{0}=1$ and $F_1 = 1 \le 2^1$. Now consider the ratio: $F_{n+1}/F_n$. If we show that this is less than or equal to 2, we win.

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = \frac{F_n + F_{n-1}}{F_n} = 1 + \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}$$

Then noting that this is a strictly increasing sequence for $n\ge 2$ we have that:

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = 1 + \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n} \le 1 + 1 = 2$$

Thus we have the same result for the Fibonacci sequence. For your problem, try considering $h_{n+1}/h_n$ and see what you can tease out.